# Nativescript BitmapFactory resize does not work in iOS

Tags: ios, nativescript, bitmapfactory

I am using the BitmapFactory plugin to rezize pictures to save them as thumnails

```
let mutable = BitmapFactory.makeMutable(imageSource);
let rotatedBitmap = BitmapFactory.asBitmap(mutable).dispose((bmp) =>
{  
   return bmp.resize("80,80"); 
});
```

in Android it works perfectly, but in iOS the image returned is not resized. I read in some issues that this is because the iOS uses the default scaling..?
does anybody knnow how to resize images to square thumbnaile with a given size ?

I use undermentioned function...

```
 imageSource = imageSourceModule.fromFile(filepath);
        try
        {
            var mutable = BitmapFactory.makeMutable(imageSource); 
            var ThumbBitmap = BitmapFactory.asBitmap(mutable).dispose((bmp) =>
            {   
                var optisizestring = "25,25";
                test =  bmp.resize(optisizestring); 
                base64JPEG = test.toBase64(BitmapFactory.OutputFormat.JPEG, 75);
                img = imageSource.fromBase64(base64JPEG);
                resolve( "data:image/png;base64," + base64JPEG);                
                global.gc(); // tried with \ without   garbage collection here
             });
        } catch(ex) { console.log("errds " + ex); resolve (null);}
```

(in the BitmapFactory-plugin) BitmapFactory.ios.js i changed the resize function

```
iOSImage.prototype._resize = function(newSize) {
    var oldImg = this._nativeObject;
    try {
            var ns = CGSizeMake(newSize.width, newSize.height);
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(ns);
            var context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
            oldImg.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0,ns.width, ns.height));
            return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        }
  finally 
        {
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        }
};

// // [INTERNAL] _resize()  Original
// iOSImage.prototype._resize = function(newSize) {
//     var oldImg = this._nativeObject;

//     try {
//         var ns = CGSizeMake(newSize.width, newSize.height);
//         UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(ns, false, 0.0);

//         oldImg.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0,
//                                      ns.width, ns.height));

//         return new iOSImage(UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext());
//     }
//     finally {
//          UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
//     }
// };
```

Comment: Have the same issue, solutions?

Comment: I actually ended up changing the bitmapfacory plugin and putting it in my project. this worked for me.